# setting environment variables programmatically

Tags: r, environment-variables

In R, I can set environment variables "manually", for example:

```
Sys.setenv(TODAY = "Friday")
```

But what if the environment variable name and value are stored in R objects?

```
var.name  <- "TODAY"
var.value <- "Friday"
```

I wrote this:

```
expr <- paste("Sys.setenv(", var.name, " = '", var.value, "')", sep = "")
expr
# [1] "Sys.setenv(TODAY = 'Friday')"
eval(parse(text = expr))
```

which does work:

```
Sys.getenv("TODAY")
# 1] "Friday"
```

but I find it quite ugly. Is there a better way? Thank you.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use `do.call` to call the function with that named argument:

```
args = list(var.value)
names(args) = var.name
do.call(Sys.setenv, args)
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
.Internal(Sys.setenv(var.name, var.value))
```

Comment: +1 but don't do this in a package, as it's against CRAN policies.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich, can you please elaborate on your comment? Is it because `.Internal` functions are not subject to the same (strict) backward compatibility requirements?

Comment: @flodel: see the [CRAN Repository Policy](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/policies.html): "CRAN packages should use only the public API..."

Answer (score 1):

This is a variant of the accepted answer, but if you want to pack this into a single line, and/or avoid generating the intermediate `args` object, you can use `setNames` to get a named character vector, then coerce to list with `as.list`:

```
do.call(Sys.setenv, as.list(setNames(var.value, var.name)))
```